# Web crawler crashes after collecting 2 pages of data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am scraping a website that cells iPhone cases.

The web scraper should collect the name of the product and the price. When I run the program my code crashes and I get this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "phonecases.py", line 12, in <module>
>     price = content.find(class_="products-grid-price").get_text().replace('\n','')
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
> ```

This is because some items are on sale, when an item is not on sale the class is `products-grid-price` and when an item is on sale the class is `products-grid-price-sale`.
Therefore, the program collects the data I want until it reaches an item on sale and then it crashes.

How do I fix my program so that it either skips the item on sale or collects them as a different data point?

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cellphonecases.com/Apple-Iphone-11-C2429.html?page='
    for page in range(1, 5):
        response = requests.get(url + str(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        contents = soup.find_all(class_="products-grid-container-out")

    for content in contents:
        title = content.find(class_="products-gridname").get_text().replace('\n','')
        price = content.find(class_="products-grid-price").get_text().replace('\n','')
        print(title, price)
```

Comment: _How to I fix my program so that it either skips the item on sale or collects them as a different data point?_ Is there an issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Can't you just check for an element with the first class, and if there isn't one then switch to the second?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), for example:

```
price = None
try:
    price = content.find(class_="products-grid-price").get_text().replace('\n','')
except:
    price = content.find(class_="products-grid-price-sale").get_text().replace('\n','')
```

It will first try the code, if it throws an exception (error) it will catch it and run the code in the except block.

Or something like:

```
price = None
price_field = content.find(class_="products-grid-price")
if price_field:
    price = price_field.get_text()
else:
    price = content.find(class_="products-grid-price-sale").get_text()

# clean price
price = price.replace('\n','')
```